# Enable Compose Compiler in KMM Module

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose, kmm

I'm working on a KMM project and ran into this article while working on improving performance https://www.jetpackcompose.app/articles/how-can-I-debug-recompositions-in-jetpack-compose

My shared KMM module has a lot of data classes that are used in the UI and the section at the end of the article caught my attention.

> If you are using classes from modules that don't have compose enabled,
> the compose compiler won't be able to infer their stability

I have a composable that takes in a data class from the shared module and displays the data similar to the article. Using the Compose debug tools, I was able to confirm that the composable wasn't marked as `skippable` and the data class was marked with `unstable`

I followed the second workaround they provided wrapping the data class in another data class in the Android module and it worked to mark it as `stable` and `skippable`.

Instead of cluttering my app with tons of wrapper classes, I'd love to use their first around.

> 1. Add compose support to the module that has the data class

My question is how do you enable compose support for the shared portion of a KMM app?

I've tried enabling the plugin with the following.

```
plugins {
  id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.2.0-alpha01-dev753"
}
```

However, I can't get Gradle to resolve the plugin.

I don't see a place to do it the "normal" way of setting `compose` to be true like in the Android build.gradle.kts file.

```
android {
...
    buildFeatures {
        // Enables Jetpack Compose for this module
        compose = true
    }
...
}
```

Is there a way to add to `buildFeatures` in the shared module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this to work.

First, in the shared build.gradle.kts file, make these changes.

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.2.0"
    }
}

kotlin {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        ...
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.3.0-alpha02")
                ...
            }
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

Make sure the compiler version is the same as in your Android module's build file.

Then create a file and add an expect for the `@Immutable` compose annotation.

`expect annotation class Immutable()`

In the Android side of the shared module add

`actual typealias Immutable = androidx.compose.runtime.Immutable`

In the iOS side add a dummy version.

`actual annotation class Immutable`

You can then annotate your data classes with `@Immutable` and they will properly be marked as `stable` by Compose.

Comment: Were you seeing performance issues to prompt you to do this? For obvious reasons depending on compose in a non-ui module feels like it breaks a clean architecture approach. Also mentioned in the same article "Chasing complete skippability for every composable in your app is a premature optimization. Being skippable actually adds a small overhead of its own which may not be worth it.." - I wonder if you can add some tangible metrics to show an improvement in performance, since the article doesn't offer any? I really hope this is handled better in future releases ..

Comment: Yeah, I was having quite a bit of stuttering on a custom rotating menu. I tracked down that each menu item was recomposing each frame when scrolling which lead me to that article. In my case, I saw about a 2x framerate improvement and can confirm that the menu items aren't recomposing anymore. I later made some other improvements to avoid recomposition (mostly using lambda versions of modifiers) and the effect from the above change is much smaller now so it might not always be worth doing.

Comment: Ok, well glad it had some useful improvements.  My reason for asking I am in a similar situation with a dozen or so kmm modules used in a mono repo for multiple applications; Android, iOS and Desktop, some have value/data classes used by the ui layer but so far haven't encountered any major performance snags with compose, so I'd be reluctant to add Compose depedendency in non-ui modules unless the gain was significant. As a side did you try a release build apk at all?  I have notiiced significant improvements over a debug variant in performance for compose apps.

Comment: I just tried a release build and the improvements were pretty minor. Maybe 5-10%. By far the biggest improvement I made was using lambda versions of modifiers to prevent recomposition (for example using ```.graphicsLayer { rotationZ = angle }``` instead of ```.rotate(angle)```